# W3SVC service stopping error

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis

I have a web server ( IIS 7.5 , windows 2008 64 Bit web server ed) and notice that in last few days all web sites on server stopped and cant browser by visitor.
I check the event log but I didnt see any things related to this problem.
When I try to restart IIS i got error on W3SVC serivce.When IIS try to STOP it, W3SVC goes to stopping state and never stop. so I can't start it again.
I try and find that I never can restart the W3SVC and when IIS work fine if I try to restart this service, it goes to stopping and never stop.

1- how can I find the problem on IIS? ( i have several asp.net app host on it )
2- how can I fix W3SVC service stopping problem?

Thanks

Mehdi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if you try this from an elevated command prompt?

```
net stop w3svc
net stop IISAdmin
net start IISAdmin
net start w3svc
```

Comment: I would also throw a: `net stop "ASP.NET State Service" & net start "ASP.NET State Service"` in there for good measure when wanting to give IIS a "full restart".

Comment: Good tip @thelsdj. +1 for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I try this command but W3svc goes to stopping ... status and never stop. also the main problem is how can I find the problem that prevent IIS works correctly.