# W3SVC keeps crashing

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis

We have a workstation (Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit,IIS 7.5),and a web project deployed running in the same machine.Recently we received error that users cannot access web pages.Since then,we have learned IIS has stopped working and **W3SVC service** is not running.
We also tried to re-run this service but it didn't work.For the last time,uninstalled and reinstalled **IIS Web Admin** then it worked for some time but again crashed.

I searched for similar errors like [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/228284/w3svc-service-stopping-error),solutions here did not even work.

How can i fix this problem ?

Best Regards

Comment: Can you check the application and system logs and post any pertinent findings?

Comment: I checked event logs regarding the problem,only errors I found are IIS-W3SVC-PerfCounters(EventID:2002) and IISInfoCtrs(EventID:1001).Could they possibly cause service to stop ?

Comment: Not likely.  Anything else in there?

Comment: Nothing like errors,I only found specific services in order to be worked for IIS are disabled,not working.Starting them individually,solved my case.However,they may again stop in the future,that's the reason i'm looking for.

Comment: Are the service startup types set to Automatic?

Comment: They were set to Automatic until they stopped,now disabled somehow

Comment: Perhaps,some kind of group policy disables IIS-based services ? If so,what should I do ?

Comment: If it were GPO based, you'd find it under: Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->Security Settings->System Services
IIS Admin Service

Comment: I cannot find System Services under Security Settings.I'm the administrator of server.How can I find System Services root

Comment: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/File_Servers/Active_Directory/Q_23811503.html

Comment: @Chris that link does not help !